# Flags with image instead of link

Tags: views, panels, theming, flags

I have two flags defined in my site (`false_negative_flag` and `false_negative_flag_passed`). Each flag has different Flag link text.

In views, I have two displays. I have a flag link in each of these views, one with the first flag, the other with the second one. The link text shows correctly on both displays. I wanted to have images instead of the link text so I added the following css:

```
.flag-wrapper.{false_negative_flag} a.flag-action {
    background: url(http://.../files/failed.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent:-9999em;
}
.flag-wrapper.{false_negative_flag} a.unflag-action {
    background: url(http://.../files/passed.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent:-9999em;
}
.flag-wrapper.{false_negative_flag_passed} a.flag-action {
    background: url(http://.../files/passed.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent:-9999em;
}
.flag-wrapper.{false_negative_flag_passed} a.unflag-action {
    background: url(http://.../files/warning.png) no-repeat center center;
    border:none;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    color: transparent;
    text-indent:-9999em;
}
```

There are 3 different images I use but in my views I always see the `passed` and `warning` ones (the last two entries of the css). Is there any error in my css?

NOTE: I'm using the displays in Panels, don't know if it's relevant.

EDIT after first answer: I got the css I'm using from the link in this answer. I simply duplicated and in the second part I added the second flag machine name. The problem is that now it ignores the first two blocks of the css.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with flags u should use "-", not underscores and there are should be class names started with flag-: **flag-false-negative-flag-passed**